# Importing a dictionary from a module which has its name in a variable

Tags: python

I wrote a program which encode all files inside a folder into strings and write it to a pyfile as a dictionary.

The name of the py file to be created is given along with the path, the dictionary is created by adding " = data" to its name. For instance:

```
pyfilename = "images.py"
```

then the dictionary with the images is written into this file as `imagesdata`.

Now I need to decode any py file previously encoded in this manner.

I give only the name of the py file in a variable and the program gets all other names from this and imports the correct dictionary from the correct module with the given name. Sample code given below.

```
name2decode = images.py
dictname = name2decode + "data"
```

the program should do

```
from name2decode import dictname
```

where `name2decode` and `dictnames` are variables. I tried using the `__import__("name2decode.dictname")` syntax but for some reason this does not work. Maybe I got the syntax wrong.

How can this be done?

Comment: `name2decode = images.py` - shouldn't that be `name2decode = "images.py"`? What does *"does not work"* mean - if an error, provide the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the module name, then use `getattr()` to get the dictionary object from that:

```
import importlib
import os.path

name2decode = os.path.splitext(name2decode)[0]
module = importlib.import_module(name2decode)
dictionary = getattr(module, dictname)
```

Note that you need to remove the `.py` extension when importing!

Comment: can you please explain the line name2decode = os.path.splitext(name2decode)[0]? What does splittext and [0] do?

Comment: @wookie: [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) splits a filename into a base and extension tuple, and `[0]` selects just the base part. It gives you the `images` part of `images.py`.

Comment: Thank you. If I know the file extension of the file that I am seeking here, as an ex. "images.py" can i use name2decode = filename[:-3] which will drop the ".py" part and give the "images" part?

Comment: @wookie: if you know for certain that it'll always be those 3 characters, sure.